# PostgreSQL - select the results of two subqueries

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 complex queries that are both subqueries in postgres, the results of which are:

```
q1_results = id , delta , metric_1
q2_results = id , delta , metric_2
```

i'd like to combine the results of the queries, so the outer query can access either:

```
results_a = id , delta , metric_1 , metric_2
results_b = id , delta , combined_metric
```

i can't figure out how to do this.  online searches keep leading me to `UNION` , but that keeps the metrics in the same column. i need to keep them split.

Comment: Would a view table be helpful?

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for `NATURAL OUTER JOIN` and some later post-processing for getting `combined_metric`.

Comment: i'd like to do everything within the pg selects / updates.  i started working on an `OUTER JOIN` solution, but that creates a a 6column wide field with lots of NULLs; the `case` statements seemed to be getting needlessly complex.

Comment: `NATURAL` will make your table 4 columns wide by collapsing fields with the same name and using them as a join target so you will get `id` and `delta` merged from both tables plus `metric_1` from one side and `metric_2` from another.

Comment: I didn't register the `NATURAL`. You're right!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking in the question and the comments, but it sounds like you might be looking for a full join with a bunch of coalesce statements, e.g.:

```
-- create view at your option, e.g.:
-- create view combined_query as
select coalesce(a.id, b.id) as id,
       coalesce(a.delta, b.delta) as delta,
       a.metric1 as metric1,
       b.metric2 as metric2,
       coalesce(a.metric1,0) + coalesce(b.metric2,0) as combined
from   (...) as results_a a
full join (...) as results_b b on a.id = b.id -- and a.delta = b.delta maybe?
```

Comment: Be wary of joining that view with anything, though. Performance will be terrible if you try it. :-)

Comment: yeah.  this is actually part of a nightly job to cache some data for on-demand analytics processing.  we take a bit of a hit, but running this at 3am and doing everything in-memory saves a lot of time during the day.

Comment: Oh, in that case, consider a materialized view if you've upgraded to PG 9.3. And index it as needed.